# How to get rid of desktop.ini from a Windows Server 2008 desktop safely?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, desktop

Useless `desktop.ini` icon irritates me by being displayed on my Server desktop.

I don't want to disable hidden files showing globally but would like to get rid of this particular one and make sure it won't return.

Can I accomplish this safely?

PS: I know what are desktop.ini files for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it'll probably just reappear. It's just part of Windows and you've chosen to display "under the hood" items.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it will likely keep coming back unless you hide system files.

EDIT: Choosing to hide system files wont prevent it from coming back, just it being visible.